# Data not shown in view Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am new in Codeigniter and i have problem when trying to display data in view page. I have follow Codeigniter documentation, tutorials and questions in stackoverflow but still no answer can help me althought i run the tutorial and it work perfectly. but when i implement in my code, it give me an error. Hope you guys can help me. I am not sure what the problem. Thank you in advanced.

**A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: b
Filename: home/adminviewbranch.php
Line Number: 81**

**Form.php(controller)**

```
public function view_branch(){
    $this->load->model('branch_model');
    $data = array();
    $data['b'] = $this->branch_model->branch_view();
    $this->load->view('home/adminviewbranch', $data);
}
```

**branch_model.php(model)**

```
 public function branch_view(){
     //data is retrive from this query
     $query = $this->db->get('branch');  
     return $query;
 }
```

**adminviewbranch.php(view)**

```
<div id="page" class="container">
    <table id="table_id" class="display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Branch Name</th>
                <th>Branch Address</th>
                <th>Branch Contact</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            if(count($b)>0) {
                foreach ($b as $row) {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?=$row->branch_name;?></td>
                        <td><?=$row->branch_add;?></td>
                        <td><?=$row->branch_Hp;?></td>
                        <td><?=$row->branch_Hp;?></td>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            else {
                echo "No Record found!";
            }
            ?>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: which codeigniter version do you use?

Comment: controller and model file names must have the first letter capitalized as per latest version if your model should be Branch_model.php not branch_php per latest version

Comment: hi. sorry i am late. i am using codeigniter 3.1.3. I have change the model and controller name as you said.thanks..

Answer (score 0):

in foreach do `foreach ($b->result() as $row)`

Comment: This could use [more explanation to avoid deletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/175564).

Answer (score 0):

I think there is missing function in your foreach.

Try this:

```
<?php
    if(count($b)>0)
      {
       foreach ($b->result() as $row){
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your model code to following

```
public function branch_view(){

 //data is retrive from this query
 $query = $this->db->get('branch');

 return $query->result_array(); // this allows you to fetch results in the form of multidimentional array
}
```

Then you can access it in view as

```
<?php
    if(count($b)>0)
    {
        foreach ($b as $row)
        {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?=$row['branch_name'];?></td>
                <td><?=$row['branch_add'];?></td>
                <td><?=$row['branch_Hp'];?></td>
                <td>Action</td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<tr colspan='3'><td>No Record found!</td></tr>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hi.thank you for your reply. But i have tried this before but it still say undefined variable for $b in view.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your model code like below

```
public function branch_view(){

 //data is retrive from this query
$query = $this->db->get('branch')->result_array();  
return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your model is not result anything.you can check with `print_r()` function.you must use be returning with object or array.`return $query->result();`
and your view must be `foreach($tes as $t){$t->your_view}`
or  `return $query->row();`
 with single data `$row->your_view`

Answer (score 0):

in model change this line

```
$query = $this->db->get('branch');
```

to

```
$query = $this->db->get('branch')->result();
```

(OR) 
in view change this lines

```
<?php
if(count($b)>0) {
    foreach ($b as $row) {
```

?>
to

```
<?php
if($b->num_rows()>0) {
foreach ($b->result() as $row) {
```

?>